# How can you set the fill-color of a shape from an ImageView without affecting the stroke-color?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I would like to use the same shape for several ImageViews but with different fill colors. I have already tried to use the app: tint attribute for this, but the stroke-color then had the same color as the fill-color.

Comment: How is your shape implemented? is it xml drawable ?

Comment: Yes, in a XML-file

Comment: I posted an answer, plz check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your xml shape drawable into two shape drawables, one for `fill` and the other for `stroke`. Then you can use `shape_fill` drawable with background (you can use it with `backgroundTint` as well), and use `shape_stroke` with your ImageView's `src` attribute (you can use it also with `tint`).

Here is some example code:

shape_stroke.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="#FF0000" android:width="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

shape_fill.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

Example usage with ImageView:

```
    <!-- example one green shape with cyan stroke -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_fill"
        android:backgroundTint="#00FF00"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_stroke"
        app:tint="#00ffff" />

    <!-- example two yello shape with purple stroke -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_fill"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFF00"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_stroke"
        app:tint="#ff00ff" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply!  I think that's the only option, even if it's probably not officially intended.